# Eliminate array elements based on minimum and maximum value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array as below.

```
$denominations = array(100, 200, 500, 1000, 5000);
```

And dynamic minimum and maximum value,

For example;

```
$minimumValue = 150;
$maximumValue = 700;
```

So my denomination array should eliminate 100 and 1000 above.

I know I can do it by for loop. But to simplify my coding is there any array function can do this?

Comment: "*So my denomination array should eliminate 100 and 1000 above*". Should eliminate `5000` as well, right?

Comment: @D4V1D yes you are right

Comment: Thanks all. Most of the answers solves my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select valid items by array_filter

```
$minimumValue = 150;
$maximumValue = 700;

$new = array_filter($denominations, 
     function($v) use($minimumValue, $maximumValue) 
         { return ($v > $minimumValue && $v < $maximumValue); });
```

Answer (score 2):

`array_map` & `array_filter` can help -

```
$denominations = array(100, 200, 500, 1000, 5000);
$minimumValue = 150;
$maximumValue = 700;
$new = array_map(function($a) use($minimumValue, $maximumValue) {
    if($a > $minimumValue && $a < $maximumValue) {
        return $a;
    }
}, $denominations); // Will return the values if satisfied else null will be set

$new = array_filter($new); // Filter out the null values
```

With `array_filter` -

```
$new = array_filter($denominations , function($a) use($minimumValue, $maximumValue) {
    if($a > $minimumValue && $a < $maximumValue) {
        return $a;
    }
});
```

Comment: Delete the 1st :))))))

Comment: @splash58 There is nothing wrong with that also. This may help for other situation if required. :)

Comment: Both the answers works.. Its not a wrong to have more than one method two solve one problems ;-)

Comment: Just about *This may help for other situation* , I don't say it doesn't work

Comment: @splash58 Sometimes it may need to count how many are eliminated or which keys are eliminated.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested yet but should be something like this using `array_filter` function:

```
<?php
$denominations = array(100, 200, 500, 1000, 5000);

$minimumValue = 150;
$maximumValue = 700;

$denominations = array_filter($denominations , function($key, $value) {
    return $value >= $minimumValue && $value <= $maximumValue;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH)); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `array_filter` as

```
$denominations = array(100, 200, 500, 1000, 5000);
$minimumValue = 150;
$maximumValue = 700;
array_filter($denominations,function($v) use(&$result,$minimumValue,$maximumValue)
{
 if($v > $minimumValue && $v < $maximumValue) 
     $result[] = $v;
});
print_r($result);
```

[**Fiddle**](https://eval.in/381678)